# How to pass arguement to named callback in higher order functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, lodash

I'm trying to figure out how do I pass in an argument to a named callback function?

For example I have

```
   var result = this.data;

   var groupFilter = $("#groupSelect");
   var functionFilter = $("#functionSelect");
   var skillFilter = $("#skillSelect");

   var uniqSkils = _(result).map('skill').uniq().map(populateDropdown(skillFilter));
   var uniqFunctions = _(result).map('function').uniq().map(populateDropdown(functionFilter));
   var uniqgroups = _(result).map('group').uniq().map(populateDropdown(groupFilter));

    function populateDropdown(element) {
        element.append($('<option>', {
            value: item,
            text: item
        }))
    }
```

Essentially the result contains dropdown values for three elements. I've created 3 arrays, I've then called uniq for obvious reasons, then I want to go through each array, each item and add it to the correct elements.

But I can't figure out how to pass in the element when using a named callback

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have your populateDropdown return a closure that is bound to a particular element:

```
function populateDropdown(element) {
    return function(item) {
        element.append($('<option>', {
            value: item,
            text: item
        }));
    }
}
```

Comment: Still won't work with curried lodash's `map` function. See an answer from Rory McCrossan, a good one (although using `this` is a doubtful practice when other part of the code follows functional approach).

Comment: Why won't it work? It looks like it works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/zp9n1zed/ (though I could be missing something) @RishatMuhametshin